# Android APK inputstream of zipentry gives different result on phone and computer

Tags: java, android, apk, inputstream

I am scanning a APK file and reading ZipEntry on mobile device in an app using java and on windows 10 computer using a java program. The code is exactly the same. I get exactly the same CRC value of the entry. But when I read the first 512 bytes using InputStream of this entry,  I am getting different results. Why? What I am doing wrong? Please help....

I expect exactly the same value as apk is same. CRC value indicates that. How and what I have to change in code to get the same value?

### Java program on computer

```
        JarFile zipFile = new JarFile("foo.apk");
        Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = zipFile.entries();

        while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {

            ZipEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
            if (entry.getName() != null && entry.getName().indexOf("libfooooo.so") >= 0) {

                InputStream stream = zipFile.getInputStream(entry);

                int bytesRead;
                final int bufferSize = 512;
                final byte[] buffer2 = new byte[bufferSize];

                bytesRead = stream.read(buffer2, 0, 512);

                String libstr= new String(buffer2);

                stream.close();

                System.out.println("IN JAVA "+entry.getName()+" CRC="+entry.getCrc()+"    Hashcode="+ libstr.hashCode()+"  ");
            }

        }

        zipFile.close();
```

### Java program on computer

```
        JarFile zipFile = new JarFile(this.getApplicationInfo().sourceDir);
        Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = zipFile.entries();

        while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {

            ZipEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
            if (entry.getName() != null && entry.getName().indexOf("libfooooo.so") >= 0) {

                InputStream stream = zipFile.getInputStream(entry);

                int bytesRead;
                final int bufferSize = 512;
                final byte[] buffer2 = new byte[bufferSize];

                bytesRead = stream.read(buffer2, 0, 512);

                String libstr= new String(buffer2);

                stream.close();

                System.out.println("IN APP "+entry.getName()+" CRC="+entry.getCrc()+"    Hashcode="+ libstr.hashCode()+"  ");
            }

        }

        zipFile.close();
```

The results are like:

- IN JAVA libfooooo.so CRC=1567899977  Hashcode=-165566890
- IN APP  libfooooo.so CRC=1567899977  Hashcode=196443742

Comment: Have you compared if you are getting the same number of bytes -> `bytesRead`?512 is the maximum number of bytes that are returned by `stream.read` but at any time it may be less than 512. If you want to make sure use `DataInputStream` and call `readFully(buffer2)` instead of `read`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the stream before you build the String (and compute the hash). Different implementations of the ZipInputStream may be more or less lazy in how eagerly they read the data, thus when you build the String, it's possible your byte array is empty or half empty.

I'd recommend the following code:

```
try (ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(this.getApplicationInfo().sourceDir)) {
    Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = zipFile.entries();
    while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
        ZipEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
        if (entry.getName() != null && entry.getName().indexOf("libfooooo.so") >= 0) {
            final int bufferSize = 512;
            final byte[] buffer2 = new byte[bufferSize];
            try (InputStream stream = zipFile.getInputStream(entry)) {
                int bytesRead = stream.read(buffer2, 0, 512);                
            }
            System.out.println(
                "IN APP " + entry.getName() + " CRC="+entry.getCrc() 
                    + " Hashcode=" + Arrays.hashCode(buffer2));
        }
    }
}
```